# Laravel : Axios not saving the data in edit page

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, axios

I create an edit page to edit the data. After the user edits the form. The form should be saved. But in my case I can't save the form it's showing error. 
[image]
I facing this error.

ReminderComponent.vue

```
<script>
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import axios from 'axios'
    import VueAxios from 'vue-axios' 
    import MarkdownIt from 'markdown-it'
    import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
    var msg_editor;
    Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);


    const md = new MarkdownIt({
        linkify: true
    })

  export default {
    props: ['email_creation_link', 'email_index_route', 'email_edit_route','conditions','modules','mailtemplates'],

    components: {


    },


    data() {
        return {
            template: 
             {
                subject: '',
                message: '' ,
                days: '',
                condition_id: 1,

            },
            options:[
                {
                    display:'Client Name',
                    actual:'Client name'
                }, 
                {
                    display:'Joined Date',
                    actual:'Joined date'
                },
                {
                    display:'Module Name',
                    actual:'Module name'
                },
                {
                    display:'Last Seen',
                    actual:'Last seen'
                },
            ],


              showName: false,


        }
    },


    mounted(){
            var self = this;

            ClassicEditor
            .create(document.querySelector( "#msg"),
                {
                })
            .then(editor => {
                msg_editor = editor;
                editor.model.document.on( 'change:data', () => {
                    self.template.message = msg_editor.getData();
                });
            })

            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            })


            if (this.mailtemplates) {
                    this.template=this.mailtemplates;
            }



        }, 

    methods: {

        //Drag items
        dragstart: function(item, e){
            this.draggingItem = item;
            e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', item.actual);
        },
        dragend: function(item,e) {
            e.target.style.opacity = 1;
        },
        dragenter: function(item, e) {
            this.draggingItem = item;
        },
        //content
        replaceVariables(input)
        {
            let updated = input
            return updated
        },
        //hidecontent
        showHide: function(e)
        {
            console.log("Show "+e.target.value+ " fields")
            this.showName = e.target.value !== ''
        },
        fetch()
        {
            //request data
            axios.get(this.email_index_route,this.template)
                .then((res) => {
                    this.template = res.data.template;

                })
            **axios.get(this.email_edit_route,this.mailtemplates)
                .then((res) => {
                    this.mailtemplates = res.data.template;

                })**
        },
        save()
        {
            //save data to db
            axios.post(this.email_index_route, this.template)
                .then((res) => {
                    alert('Mail sent successfull!')
                })
            **axios.post(this.email_edit_route, this.mailtemplates)
                .then((res) => {
                    alert('Mail sent successfull!')
                })**
        },
        addToMail: function(type, text)
        {
            if (type == 'message') {
                this.template.message += text;
                msg_editor.setData(this.template.message);
            }
        },

        //user name replace
        replaceVariables() {
            return this.replaceVariables(this.options || '')
        },
    }
  }
</script>
```

I think this area causing problem but i can't find the solution.

```
axios.get(this.email_edit_route,this.mailtemplates)
   .then((res) => {
      this.mailtemplates = res.data.template;

      })

axios.post(this.email_edit_route, this.mailtemplates)
      .then((res) => {
          alert('Mail sent successfull!')
 })
```

route file

```
Route::get('api/email/create', ['as' => 'email.create', 'uses' => 'Havence\AutoMailController@create']);
    Route::get('automail/mail', 'Havence\AutoMailController@mail');
    Route::get('automail/index',['as'=>'email.index','uses' => 'Havence\AutoMailController@index']);
    Route::post('automail/edit/{id}',['as'=>'email.edit','uses' => 'Havence\AutoMailController@edit']);
    Route::get('automail/delete',['as'=>'email.delete','uses' => 'Havence\AutoMailController@destroy']);
```

I kept searching for this but couldn't find an answer that will make this clear.

Thanks!

Comment: are sure that your route exist in laravel ?

Comment: yes the route is exist in laravel. I will edit my route file. you look at i

Answer (score 0):

As per your error and your route file you are using `POST` method on your `edit` page but your edit method accepts only `GET` method that is why you are getting this error.[image]

**I'm getting this error**

Comment: Route::post('automail/edit/{id}',['as'=>'email.edit','uses' => 'Havence\AutoMailController@edit']); is it like this?

Comment: yes if you want to use post request then you have to use post request in you route file

Comment: yes i try to change the method but the data didn't save and getting some other. @Sehdev

Comment: i attach over there

Comment: Add this line at the top `import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'`

Comment: I already add that line. still facing the same issue. @Sehdev

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209035/discussion-between-sehdev-and-navanitha-moorthy).